# Lagrange's theorem elementary number theory proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the following notes [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mazag/nt/lecture6.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emazag/nt/lecture6.pdf) the proof of Lagrange's theorem (Theorem 1.2), I am unsure as to how the final line is produced. Namely that the number of zeroes of $f(x)\mod p$ is at most the sum of the number of zeroes of its factorization which in this case we have $g(x)$ and $x-a$.

Comment: A product is $0$ modulo $p$ if and only if one of the factors is $0$ modulo $p$. Since $f(x)\equiv g(x)(x-a)\pmod{p}$, if $f(b)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, then $g(b)(b-a)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, so $g(b)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ or $b-a\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ (since $p$ divides a product if and only if it divides at least one of the factors).

Comment: How do we know these are the only solutions?

Comment: Huh? Because any solution will necessarily force either $g(b)$ to be $0$, or $(b-a)$ to be $0$ (modulo $p$). If $g(b)\not\equiv 0$ and $(b-a)\not\equiv 0$, then $g(b)(b-a)\not\equiv 0$, so $f(b)\not\equiv 0$. What is the problem?

Comment: You may find it helpful to read the ]proof of the [BiFactor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677084/242), and its linked post(s).